# how select data from table and print

Tags: php

I looked but now nothing, there is some way to select something from a table.

**For example:**

two text boxes `number1` and `number2` and enter 10 and 20, then print all records in a table from register 10 to 20.

It is possible to do with

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM crm_vendas WHERE venda_id BETWEEN 'number1' and '$ number2'";
```

and also with

```
while ($ row =?
```

if someone can indicate something or help I would appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use prepared statements.  Also, you do not put backticks around the entire query line.  The i's in the bind_param line indicated that the two variables you're using are integers.

```
    $number1 = 0;
    $number2 = 100;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM crm_vendas WHERE venda_id BETWEEN ? AND ?";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $number1, $number2);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    echo '<table>';
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($row as $columnValue){
            echo '<td><p>'.$columnValue.'</p></td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';

    $result->close();
    $stmt->close();
```